# Failure Delivering Results with HashMap between 2 activities

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap, onactivityresult

**Background:**

- There are two activities
- 1x (MainActivity), 1x (SubActivity - Activity with a ListView)
- Main Activity extends FragmentActivity and the Infos will be used in a Fragment
- SubActivity will open when a MenuItem of MainActivity will be clicked.
- Using a HashMap for the ListView

**My Goal:**

- The HashMap values of the clicked Item should be send back to the MainActivity and SubActivity (with the ListView) should be closed.

**Problem:**

```
java.lang.RunTimeException: Failure delivering results ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, 
result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity.
```

I think I made a huge mistake but I couldn't solve it.

---

switch case from **onOptionsItemSelected** and **onActivityResult** are in the **MainActivity**:

- PICKED has the value 1;

  switch (item.getItemId()) {

  ```
  case R.id.icon:
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HeroListActivity.class);
      MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, PICKED);
      return true;
  default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  } 



  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (requestCode == 1) {
              Intent intent = getIntent();
              HashMap<String, String> aList = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
              Log.d("HashMap", aList.get("Name"));
          }
  ```

  }

---

**onItemClick** in the **SubActivity** with the ListView:

- onItemClick is working and I get the correct data from the HashMap when I use Log.d.

  ```
  HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
  Log.d("onItemClick", ""+o);

  Intent intent = new Intent();

  intent.putExtra("map", o);
  setResult(RESULTS_OK, intent);
  finish();
  ```

---

I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to split the calls to the two activities? It sounds like your thread is really tied up and cannot do two things at once.

Comment: @Eenvincible I started to work with android several months ago, so I'm not experienced enough to answer that question. But I'm open for any suggestions.

Comment: try adding the @Override keyword to your onActivityResult() method - might not resolve your issue but still a good practice.

Comment: @notrix Already had @ Override before the onActivityResult() method and removed it from my post, because it destroyed the layout a bit. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this line in your `onActivityResult()` method

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
```

with this:

```
 Intent intent = data;
```

`data` is the name of a parameter you are passing in - that's where your extras reside. `getIntent()` call returns a `null` intent in this instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now. I also got the Keys + Values from the Hashmap and saved it into String and can start to process the data. Here is a Pastebin Link to the [current onActivityResult version](http://pastebin.com/kUXiiUCt), so other users can get the working code.